# Unable to use a shared folder in VBox Ubuntu guest that was upgraded from 20.10 to 21.04

Tags: virtualbox, shared-folders, 21.04

The **host machine** is Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop with VirtualBox version 6.1.16. The **guest machine** was also Ubuntu 20.10 Desktop with the latest (6.1.16) VB Guest Additions. I was able to use shared folders (shared from Host to Guest) from the "normal" Ubuntu user in the guest machine, since this user was also in the group `vboxsf` and the shared folder was mounted in the guest machine with permissions `drwxrwx---  root  vboxsf`.

Now, after I upgraded (using `do-release-upgrade`) the **guest machine** to 21.04, I am no longer able to access the shared folder from the normal user in the guest machine, because the shared folder is mounted with permissions `drwxr-x---  root  root` in the guest.

I tried to re-install GAs, with no change.

Nothing has changed on the **host** machine and a "clone" of the same old (20.10) **guest** works as expected (shared folders are mounted with permissions `drwxrwx---  root  vboxsf` as normal).

Note: As a side note, I need to mention that clipboard sharing also stopped working for the guest that was upgraded to 21.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There was an error in the file `/var/log/vboxadd-setup.log.1`, something like this:

```
[...]
In file included from /tmp/vbox.0/combined-os-specific.c:33:
/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c: In function ‘rtR0MemObjLinuxVMap’:
/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:560:34: error: implicit declaration of function ‘alloc_vm_area’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  560 |                 pMemLnx->pArea = alloc_vm_area(pMemLnx->Core.cb, papPtes); /* Note! pArea->nr_pages is not set. */
      |                                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/vbox.0/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c:560:32: warning: assignment to ‘struct vm_struct *’ from ‘int’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
  560 |                 pMemLnx->pArea = alloc_vm_area(pMemLnx->Core.cb, papPtes); /* Note! pArea->nr_pages is not set. */
      |                                ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:287: /tmp/vbox.0/combined-os-specific.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1837: /tmp/vbox.0] Error 2
make: *** [/tmp/vbox.0/Makefile-footer.gmk:117: vboxguest] Error 2
```

[Some further investigation showed](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/virtualbox-shared-folders-on-current-4175687660/)  that the  *"subroutine (alloc_vm_area) was removed from linux 5.10."*

So, I downloaded the latest `VBoxGuestAdditions_6.1.22.iso` from
https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/6.1.22/ and reinstalled it on the guest. Although my VirtualBox Manager on the **host** machine is at version 6.1.16, the problem in the **guest** is solved now.